# Castle Windsor and registering types from in memory assemblies; is it possible?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

We have an applicaion which compiles a number of code classes to an number of in memory assemblies when it starts up. I've being trying to register these types in Castle Windsor but it cannot instantiate them; it says type types cannot be found.

Does anyone know if this is possible?
I'm using an XML Configuration file and have the DLL's compiled before I instantiate the Windsor Container.
Below is an example of the configuration I am using; I do not specify the DLL name in the type declaration here as there is no physical DLL on disk.

```
   <!-- Register the Filtering provider, which is specified in the custom script -->
    <component id="FilteringProvider" 
               type="Optimus.Scripts.Filtering.FilteringProvider"
               service="Optimus.Filtering.Lib.IFilteringProvider, Optimus.Filtering.Lib"
               >
    </component>
```

Kind Regards
Noel

Comment: Have you tried registering your components by code ?

Comment: I have not tried it through code; as the requirement is for external registration. I'll give it a go anyway and see if I can achieve it that way; but am really looking for external registration.

Comment: off topic but I'm very curious why are you required to have registration in config?

Comment: We have arequirement that we have scriptable portions of our applicaion. We alloow this by pre-compiling configurable c# files which expose a fixed service interface we supply. We don't case about the names of the components or namespaces; as they will be customer specific; but we needed a way to let the customer configure the scripts to match what they had developed. XML configuration seemed the simpliest at the time. If there are other approaches I would be glad to consider them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register components from code, in a specific assembly :

```
container.Register(
    AllTypes.Of<IService>()
    .FromAssembly(myAssemly));
```

Here you will pass your dynamically compiled assembly.

http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx

Comment: Thanks mathieu. Looks like that will work for us; if we assume there will only ever be 1 instance of a particular type of service in the compiled DLL. We'll also need to upgrade to the latest version of Castle.